# Sql Server: how to transpose row to column?

Tags: sql

this is (maybe) an already asked question... but i've some difficul to solve my problem. 
I need to transpose to column a row-based query. 
I explain: 
This is my actual query result

```
Year     Month     Value
2010      Jan         19
2010      Feb         10
...
```

I need

```
Year      Jan        Feb         ...         Dec
2010      19         20          ...         ...
2011      11         ..          ...
```

Actually, my main query is very simple..

```
SELECT     SUM(QTYCALC) AS TOT, YEAR(SCHEDSTART) AS MyYear, MONTH(SCHEDSTART) AS MyMonth
FROM         PRODTABLE
GROUP BY YEAR(SCHEDSTART), MONTH(SCHEDSTART)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which DB are you using ?

Comment: Each RDBMS has a different solution. Please, post what database brand are you using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `PIVOT` to achieve that - for explanation and some examples see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx and http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx

Another option would be:

```
SELECT
YEAR(SCHEDSTART) AS MyYear, 
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 1 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS Jan,
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 2 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS Feb,
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 3 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS Mar,
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 4 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS Apr,
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 5 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS May,
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 6 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS Jun,
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 7 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS Jul,
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 8 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS Aug,
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 9 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS Sep,
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 10 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS Oct,
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 11 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS Nov,
(SELECT SUM(X.QTYCALC) FROM PRODTABLE X WHERE MONTH(X.SCHEDSTART) = 12 AND YEAR(X.SCHEDSTART) = YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)) AS Dec
FROM       PRODTABLE P
GROUP BY YEAR(P.SCHEDSTART)
```

You should check both (`PIVOT` and this) regarding performance/execution plan...